# facebook fql query to gather all posts made from app with specific "id"

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I need your help.
I have ios app with facebook
This app has many different objects which user can post to his facebook wall.
My problem is - when users post something about this object on their wall, i need mark this posts with  "id" of this objects. Every posts about this object  must be marked with this "id" (hash, etc)  and after that i need create (fql query or graph API ) to gather all posts from every users walls  which post about this object .
1) How to mark user's post with "id" ? 
2) how (fql query or graph API) must be that it can  gather specific posts from different facebook users walls

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

As of now, this isn't possible. But since fB recently launched hash tags, you can wait for the `hashtags API`.

You could workaround with [Search API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/#types), but this doesn't shows the  exact matches!

Comment: Thank you. How to about use comments instead of post?